# Xstream and Inheritance

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, abstract-class, xstream

I have a `.dat` file that contains some type of products. I'm reading the `.dat` file and then writing it as JSON and XML files. I'll explain the bug in pic after the files. Here's the problem, in XML file, there's no `productCode` while in JSON there is. I don't know what's wrong with `productCode` in XML since I'm passing `super(productCode)` in both products.

What's wrong with this code?

```
public static void xmlConverter(List<Product> products) {
    XStream xstream = new XStream();

    File xmlOutput = new File("data/Products.xml");

    PrintWriter xmlPrintWriter = null;
    try {

        xmlPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(xmlOutput);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    xmlPrintWriter.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?> \n <products>");

    xstream.alias("product", Product.class);        
    xstream.alias("refreshment", Refreshment.class);
    xstream.alias("parkingpass", ParkingPass.class);

    for (Product aProduct: products) {
        String productOutput = xstream.toXML(aProduct);
        xmlPrintWriter.write( "\n" + productOutput);
    } 

    xmlPrintWriter.write("\n");
    xmlPrintWriter.write("</products>");

    xmlPrintWriter.close();
}
```

Products.dat

```
6
ff23;R;Labatt Beer-20oz;4.99
90fa;P;25.00
3289;P;55.00
32f4;R;Caramel Popcorn;5.50
90fb;P;20.00
yp23;R;Double Cheeseburger;9.00
```

Product.java

```
package Products;

public abstract class Product {

    private String productCode;

    public Product(String productCode) {
        super();
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }

    public String getProductCode() {
        return this.productCode;

    }

    public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;

    }

    public abstract String getType();

}
```

ParkingPass.java

```
package Products;

public class ParkingPass extends Product {

    private double cost;

    public ParkingPass(String productCode, double cost) {
        super(productCode);
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public double getParkingFee() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setParkingFee(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "P";

    }

}
```

DataConverter.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

import Products.ParkingPass;
import Products.Product;
import Products.Refreshment;

public class DataConverter {

    public static List<Product> readProduct() {
        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();

        Scanner scnr = null;

        try {
            scnr = new Scanner(new File("data/Products.dat"));
            scnr.nextLine();

            Product p = null;

            while (scnr.hasNext()) {
                String line = scnr.nextLine();
                String data[] = line.split(";");

                String productCode = data[0];
                String productType = data[1];

                String name = null;
                double cost = 0.0;
                double parkingFee = 0.0;


                if (data.length == 4) {
                    name = data[2];
                    cost = Double.parseDouble(data[3]);

                } else if (data.length == 3) {
                    parkingFee = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);
                }

                if (productType.equals("R")) {
                    p = new Refreshment(productCode, name, cost);
                } else if (productType.equals("P")) {
                    p = new ParkingPass(productCode, parkingFee);
                }

                productList.add(p);
            }
            scnr.close();
            return productList;


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void jsonConverter(List<Product> products) {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        File jsonOutput = new File("data/Products.json");

        PrintWriter jsonPrintWriter = null;

        try {
            jsonPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(jsonOutput);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (Product aProduct : products) {
            String productOutput = gson.toJson(aProduct);
            jsonPrintWriter.write(productOutput + "\n");

        }
        jsonPrintWriter.close();
    }


    public static void xmlConverter(List<Product> products) {
        XStream xstream = new XStream();

        File xmlOutput = new File("data/Products.xml");

        PrintWriter xmlPrintWriter = null;
        try {

            xmlPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(xmlOutput);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        xmlPrintWriter.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?> \n <products>");

        xstream.alias("product", Product.class);        
        xstream.alias("refreshment", Refreshment.class);
        xstream.alias("parkingpass", ParkingPass.class);

        for (Product aProduct: products) {
            String productOutput = xstream.toXML(aProduct);
            xmlPrintWriter.write( "\n" + productOutput);
        } 

        xmlPrintWriter.write("\n");
        xmlPrintWriter.write("</products>");

        xmlPrintWriter.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Product> productList = readProduct();

        jsonConverter(productList);
        xmlConverter(productList);

    }
}
}
```

[XML outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12gwv.png)
[JSON outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WShjQ.png)